# How do I make the scroll wheel work in an interactive tmux session with iterm2?

Tags: bash, tmux, iterm2

I'd like to scroll through my tmux session in iterm 2. I have a mouse and when I use the scroll wheel, it adds text that looks like this

```
4M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113;24M64;113
```

Also, I got a pop-up from the application that asked if I want to make the cursor move from the scroll wheel.

I hit yes and now when I move the scroll wheel, the terminal fills with this-

```
A^[[A^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[
```

What is that and how can I disable it? I've gone into settings and turned off `mouse wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode`

Answer (score 1):

I simply added the line `set -g mouse on` in `~/.tmux.conf`, and can now use the scroll wheel with no such issues.